# Ввод в значений в терминал

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

```
NULL EQU 0
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE EQU -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE EQU -10
extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _WriteConsoleA@20
extern _ExitProcess@4
extern _ReadConsoleA@16

global Start

section .data

    Message db "hello from", 0Dh, 0Ah
    MessageLength EQU $-Message

section .bss
    StandardHandle resd 1
    Written resd 1

section .text
    Start:

          push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
          call _GetStdHandle@4
          mov dword [StandardHandle], EAX
          push NULL
          push Written
          push MessageLength
          push Message
          push dword [StandardHandle]
          call _WriteFile@20
    Read:
          push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
          call _GetStdHandle@4
          mov [StandardHandle],eax
          push NULL
          push 1
          push MessageLength
          push dword [StandardHandle]
          call _ReadConsoleA@16

    exit:

        push    NULL
        call    _ExitProcess@4
```

Я пытаюсь получить данные которые ввожу в консоль
В интернете нашел вот такой код но при запуске программа сразу завершается даже не дает возможности что то ввести. Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Как компилируете? Также желательно операционную систему указывать. Я предполагаю, что Windows, но вдруг вы нашли код для Windows, а запускаете под Linux.

Comment: nasm.exe -fwin32 main.asm; GoLink.exe /entry:Read /console kernel32.dll user32.dll .\main.obj

Comment: У меня код из вопроса собирается и работает как надо: https://i.stack.imgur.com/db0Gd.png